# Data from API is displaying in the console but not in the DOM, why?

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm learning React and a little about API's. I'm using the Destiny 2 API as a starting API to try to wrap my head around how they work.

Here is my Api.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class Api extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': 'key-here',
      },
    };

    axios
      .get('https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/4/Profile/4611686018484544046/?components=100', config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
          data: response.data,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {Array.isArray(item) &&
          item.map((object) => <p key={object.data}>{object.data.Response.profile.data.userInfo.displayName}</p>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Api;
```

The data from the API is returned as an object that contains a nested array. I can get the data to display in the console no problem.

This is the layout of the response object output to the console:

[image: console output]

I'm trying to grab the value of "displayName" and output it into the DOM, what am I doing wrong?

I have tried returning the data as JSON by doing:
`response => {return(data.json())}` and iterating through the json object using `{Object.keys(this.state.data).map((key) =>` but I have still managed to only get data in the console and not in the DOM.

Is there anything that seems to be missing? I've been stuck with this problem for several days now!

EDIT: This is the whole response from the API call

```
{
    "Response": {
        "profile": {
            "data": {
                "userInfo": {
                    "membershipType": 4,
                    "membershipId": "4611686018484544046",
                    "displayName": "Snizzy"
                },
                "dateLastPlayed": "2019-04-05T14:28:30Z",
                "versionsOwned": 31,
                "characterIds": [
                    "2305843009409505097",
                    "2305843009411764917",
                    "2305843009425764024"
                ]
            },
            "privacy": 1
        }
    },
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData": {}
}
```

Comment: `const { item } = this.state;` should be `const { data } = this.state;`

Answer (score 1):

In the render function, where you destructure you state, you have the wrong property.

`const { item } = this.state;` should be `const { data } = this.state;`

More about destructuring [here](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/).

Also, you need to make changes here:

EDIT: Actually, your data isn't even an array.  You don't have to iterate through it.

```
  <div>
     <p>{data.Response.profile.data.userInfo.displayName}</p>}
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still get no DOM output. As I'm defining the state as a const does it really matter what it's value is?

Comment: It does matter. When you destructure, you need to get properties that actually exist.  `item` isn't a property of `state`. Updated to show what else you need to change in the render function

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately this still doesn't work for me

Comment: Log `data` in the render function. What does it look like?

Comment: Oops, missed the the other `item`. It needed to be replaced by `data` so that it is `data.map()`. Try that now.

Comment: https://imgur.com/NGLcCFN this is what I get when I log the data in the render. The un-opened object is the same as before. It also logs an empty array. I noticed the other item needed editing so I changed that before I built this current version, still didn't work :(

Comment: Edited response

Comment: Now in the console I get an array that doesn't contain the data and an error that states "Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined".. Is that because I have declared 'data' as an array?

Comment: Would you be able to paste the whole response from the API?

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! I can now obtain the data!

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a check to make sure that we got back the api before running.  You might be rendering before the api call is finished.  Try using an inline statement.

```
{ item ? {Array.isArray(item) && item.map(object => (
                    <p key={object.data}>{object.data.Response.profile.data.userInfo.displayName}</p>
                ))}
:
<div>Loading...</div>
```

Comment: Do I place this in the render function? If so when I do I get an error where ```Array.isArray``` is expected to be ```Array:isArray``` but then isArray isn't defined anywhere

Comment: You could place that inline, why do you even need the Array:isArray ?  Can you just drop that ?

Comment: Even when I drop the Array:isArray my IDE expects ```item.map``` to be ```item:map``` and gives me the same error as before